# My Question Inexplicably Disappeared

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

I had asked a question on SO that had been down voted and closed as too broad. I modified the question to fit the guidelines. It began to be upvoted and several people voted to reopen the question.

Then, inexplicably, the question disappeared without a trace. One moment it was there, the next it was not. At first I thought it had been deleted, but it was not under delete questions. What happened?

EDIT: After looking at the link, the question was deleted by the community. Why does this not leave any trace?

Comment: It could still be in your profile. But, since its pretty much gone, just re-post, and try for a better title,and examinion.

Comment: Is there any info in your profile relating to the question? "one min was there, next not" is not logical. Are you saying the tab you had open disappeared too? (ie you would just see "this question is deleted" etc). What is/was the link to the question?

Comment: @James Quite literally it disappeared without a trace. I see now that it was deleted by the community.

Comment: Then it did not "disappear without a trace". :-)

Comment: I was referring to looking through at any recent activity, does it show anything about "deleted topic?"

Comment: Could you provide a link for the 10k users to be able to look at (and possibly undelete)?  Specific to this problem, how old was the question? What was its score when it was deleted? Did it have reopen votes when it was deleted? When was the last edit made?  Does it meet any of the criteria for deletion as described in [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/213963) (often known as 'roomba scripts')?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007481/rendering-an-image-in-an-image-with-captions-in-gd

Comment: Your question had 6 down and one up-vote, and a link-only answer with three downvotes. Anyway, I wouldn't want to see it undeleted in its current state (which means I think it would not fare any better if re-posted as-is).

Comment: Closed questions with a non-positive score and no positively voted answers are automatically deleted by the system after 30 days. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173513/turbocharging-the-roomba-solutions-for-premature-deletion for the specifics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does in fact leave a trace, if you [go to your question or rep summary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566339/ramsay-smith?tab=questions), you'll see a link to view deleted recent questions. As George notes, some questions that get very little or no attention at all *are* automatically culled to make way for similar questions that might fare better, which is what happened here.

We don't stick deleted content in user's faces too much, as it's not always the most positive thing to show folks. There are ways, however, to find out what happened to a specific question, but most stuff deleted in this manner is stuff that nobody cares about any longer (even the person that wrote it).

Answer (score 1):

It was deleted as part of the automated cleanup process for questions that are zero score and closed for longer than 30 days.